# Parameter change

Tags: integration, integral-domain, jacobian

i'd like to know how can i change the following domain to a simple one
$$D=\left\{(x,y)\mid \frac12\le x+y\le1 ;x^3\le y\le 4x^3\right\}$$
regarding the integral:
$$\iint\limits_D\frac{x+3y}{x^4}e^{y/x^3} \,dx \, dy$$
It's pretty obvious that i should use $u=\frac{y}{x^3}$, so that $1\le u\le4$, but i'm not so sure about the other one. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you think that your $u$ is obvious, then why is not the $v=x+y$ obvious? If you explain that, then I think you will get better help.

Comment: I added proper spacing before $dx$ and $dy$ and changed $\displaystyle\int\int$ to $\displaystyle\iint$ and $|$ to $\mid$ and $[ \cdots ]$ to $\{ \cdots \},$ etc., but one thing in the MathJax code was really weird: $x^3{\le}y$ rather than $x^3\le y$ and $1{\le}u$ rather than $1\le u.$ Putting those braces around the binary relation symbol prevented proper spacing.

Comment: @mickep Because i don't see what would be the inverse function in that case.

Comment: But maybe (hint hint) you will not need that. Try to calculate the jacobian, and you will see how the integrand was chosen.

Comment: Right, thanks..